# determine which PHP script running from PID?

Tags: php, process, centos7, pid

i need to find out which PHP script running but i have only PID. Here is CSF:

```
Account: user
Resource: Process Time
Exceeded: 20101 > 2000 (seconds)
Executable: /home/virtfs/user/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
Command Line: /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php-cgi
PID: 16659 (Parent PID:15287)
Killed: No
```

as you can see here is a problem process time which is too long i can kill this process but it start again and that is not solutions

CentOS 7.3 server

Comment: Have you checked with `ps` to see what arguments were passed to `php-cgi`? For example: `ps -f -p 16659`

Comment: nothing show, just command line from my question